# Javascript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Im new to wordpress and im trying to load javascript to it.
This is my `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp_enque_scripts',function(){
    wp_enqueue_script('$javascript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). 
    'javascript/javascript.js', [], false, true);
});
```

and this is my `javascript.js`

```
console.log("hi");
```

When i open my browser's console i cant see the printed message. Plus my script file link isnt loaded in the HTML.  What might be wrong?
Is it that i didnt specified the javascript version?

Comment: Do you first open page or console?

Comment: First i reload the page and then i press F12 for the console tab

Comment: That's may be problem why you do not see console output. It does not write to console if it's closed. First open console, then refresh page

Comment: i did this a couple of times before, its not the problem

Comment: Do you see your script file being loaded in Network tab, do you see it's link in HTML?

Comment: i forgot to mention it. No i dont see it

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is in your action name `wp_enque_scripts`. You should write `wp_enqueue_scripts`

In addition, I think you need a slash before your folder name

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts',function(){
    wp_enqueue_script('$javascript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). 
    '/javascript/javascript.js', [], false, true);
});
```